# If Elana turned off her humanity why did she still burn down her house

Tags: vampire, the-vampire-diaries

Some spoilers

In The Vampire Diaries when elana finds out that Jermey died she wants to burn down her house cause it was full of memories if people she loved that had passed away so she wants to burn  down her house so she doesn't have to look back and miss anyone or thing.

But Damon tells her to turn off her humanity Which she does but even after turning off her humanity she still burns down the house. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of 'switching off humanity' is very shady and has no particular rules.

I would say even if one's humanity is turned off, that person still knows who or what he/she is most attached to. Its like when Damon turns off his humanity, its Stefan or Elena who is closest to Damon would be able to convince him to turn it on/ bring back his humanity. Same goes for Stefan, it will be who he is closest to. If I remember correctly, when Stefan's Mom turned it off, Stefan was the one who took it upon himself to turn it back on.

There was also an idea that if you turn off your humanity and kill the one who are closest to you, then there will be no one who can make you feel again and can convince you to switch your humanity back on.

Elena has a lot of memories of her family and childhood linked with her house, burning down the house removes that from ever being used to bring back her humanity.

Comment: Oh. Ok. Thank you!

Comment: Wait, but I thought it had something to do with destroying evidence? She wanted to burn down the house so people would think Jeremy died in the fire, so the secret of the Supernaturals could still be kept?

Answer (score 0):

I think that she burnt her house down because her brother died and she did not want to go back to her house because she thought that there was nothing left for to come back to her when her humanity got turned back on because they were going to find out about the super naturals anyways

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This is difficult to understand; perhaps you could break it into sentences?  As best I can tell, you seem to recap the background of the question and say something similar to the existing answer?